# django sending mail using pre_save

Tags: django, email, django-models, django-email

1.As a part of learning django i am trying to send a mail to an email id using pre_save signal.

2.A mail should sent to an email id which is mentioned in the field.I dont't have a proper way to do using signals.Here i am giving the models.py and views.py.

```
views.py

def addbook():  


    form = BookForm

    if request.POST:
        form = BookForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            form.save()
            return redirect('/index/')
    return render_to_response('addbook.html',{ 'form':form },context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

models.py

```
class Book(models.Model):

    book_id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True,unique=True)
    book_name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    author_name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    publisher_name=models.CharField(max_length=40)
    email = models.EmailField()
    bookref = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'Book'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%d %s %s %s %s" % (self.book_id,self.book_name, self.author_name,self.publisher_name,self.email,self.bookref)
```

my requirement is an email should send automatically to the id in the field while submitting the book details.

An example about this to do will be great help.

Thanks

Comment: can any one help me in doing this

Comment: yes.I am trying to do in signals using pre_save and post_save

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the Book models, create the signal function.

```
class Book(models.Model):
    [..........]

def send_update(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if instance.author_name:
        message = "Book is updated"
        subject = "Updates"
        send_mail(subject, message, your_email,
            [instance.email,])

post_save.connect(send_update, sender=Book)
```

Comment: whether i have to make any changes in views.py

Comment: i checked with the views.py in above with new models.py code which you given,it is not sending the mail.So any changes have to do.If so please

Comment: how did you know it's not sending? How did you implement it in the models? Is there error shown?

Comment: I said it will work if Book is save or updated. Not in submitting mail.